# Javafx Tableview dont show data of ObservableList

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I have a Problem with the Tableview in JavaFX. I know there are some other posts in the forum, but i checked them and tried to use the solutions, but nothing work for me ... I have 3 Classes. One Version class, the data model. The Class which populates the data to the tableview and one thats loads the table and shows it in the UI. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Version Class (data model for table)

```
public class Version {

private final SimpleStringProperty aktVer;
private final SimpleStringProperty produktDate;
private final SimpleStringProperty aktVerForCustom;
private final SimpleStringProperty lastVer;
private final SimpleStringProperty lastVerForCustom;
private final SimpleStringProperty runOut;

Version(String aktVer, String produktDate, String aktVerForCustom, String lastVer, String lastVerForCustom, String runOut) {
    this.aktVer = new SimpleStringProperty(aktVer);
    this.produktDate = new SimpleStringProperty(produktDate);
    this.aktVerForCustom = new SimpleStringProperty(aktVerForCustom);
    this.lastVer = new SimpleStringProperty(lastVer);
    this.lastVerForCustom = new SimpleStringProperty(lastVerForCustom);
    this.runOut = new SimpleStringProperty(runOut);
}

public String getAktVer() {
    return aktVer.get();
}
public void setAktVer(String aktVer) {
    this.aktVer.set(aktVer);
}

public String getProduktDate() {
    return produktDate.get();
}
public void setProduktDate(String produktDate) {
    this.produktDate.set(produktDate);
}

public String getAktVerForCustom() {
    return aktVerForCustom.get();
}
public void setAktVerForCustom(String aktVerForCustom) {
    this.aktVerForCustom.set(aktVerForCustom);
}

public String getLastVer() {
    return lastVer.get();
}
public void setLastVer(String lastVer) {
    this.lastVer.set(lastVer);
}

public String getLastVerForCustom() {
    return lastVerForCustom.get();
}
public void setLastVerForCustom(String lastVerForCustom) {
    this.lastVerForCustom.set(lastVerForCustom);
}

public String getRunOut() {
    return runOut.get();
}
public void setRunOut(String runOut) {
    this.runOut.set(runOut);
}

public void print(){
    System.out.println("Daten:"+aktVer+"  "+produktDate+"  "+aktVerForCustom+"  "+lastVer+"  "+lastVerForCustom+"  "+runOut);
}
}
```

Table Class: (fills table with data)

```
public class VersionsManagerTabelController implements Initializable {

Connection con = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

ControllerManager cm = new ControllerManager(); 
DatabaseConnector dc = DatabaseConnector.getInstance();

ObservableList<Version> versionen = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
TableColumn tc_aktVer;
@FXML
TableColumn tc_produktDate;
@FXML
TableColumn tc_aktVerForCustom;
@FXML
TableColumn tc_lastVer;
@FXML
TableColumn tc_lastVerForCustom;
@FXML
TableColumn tc_runOut;
@FXML
TableView tv_versions;

public void populateDataForTableView(String product) throws SQLException{

    if(product.matches("toolstarLX")){
        versionen.removeAll(versionen);
        con = dc.getConnectionToDB();
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testlx");
        if (rs.next()) {
            String ver = rs.getString("akt_ver");
            String pd = rs.getString("produkt_datum");
            String ak = rs.getString("an_kunden");
            String laver = rs.getString("letzte_ver");
            String lvforcustom = rs.getString("lv_an_kunden");
            String runout = rs.getString("lauft_ab_am");
            versionen.add(new Version(ver, pd, ak, laver, lvforcustom, runout));
            versionen.get(0).print();

        }


        tv_versions.setItems(versionen);

    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {;
tc_aktVer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Version, String>("aktVer"));
}    
}
```

Table Class: (only the Method which loads the content and shows the table)

```
@FXML
private void showLxTabel(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        cm.setProduct(lx);
        tableCont.populateDataForTableView(cm.getProduct());
        AnchorPane root=null;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("VersionsManagerTabel.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
        ap_tabelContent.getChildren().clear();
        ap_tabelContent.getChildren().add(root);
        lbl_prduct_overview.setText(lx);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {Logger.getLogger(VersionsManagerMainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

Here is the FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="440.0" prefWidth="598.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="toolhouseversionsmanager.VersionsManagerTabelController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tv_versions" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="413.0" prefWidth="570.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="tc_aktVer" prefWidth="76.0" text="akt. Version" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="tc_produktDate" prefWidth="117.0" text="Produktionsdatum" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tc_aktVerForCustom" prefWidth="113.0" text="akt Ver. an Kunden" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tc_lastVer" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="letzte Version" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tc_lastVerForCustom" prefWidth="127.0" text="letz. Ver. an Kunden" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tc_runOut" prefWidth="127.0" text="läuft ab am" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the code how I get the controllers. I often that problems with controller and their references but with this approach it works well (until now??). In the other classes I create a new variable like `VersionsManagerTableController example = ControllerManager.getTableController()`

```
public class ControllerManager {

//Enthält den String des momentan ausgeählten Produkts (für Erstellen, löschen und bearbeiten von Einträgen
//in der Datenbank
StringProperty product = new SimpleStringProperty();

public String getProduct(){
    return product.get();
}

public void setProduct(String product){
    this.product.set(product);
}

public StringProperty productProperty(){
    return product;
}

//Gibt eine Referenz auf den Controller von VersionsManagerNew.fxml (Neuen Eintrag anlegen)
public VersionsManagerNewController getNewEntryController() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Pane p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("VersionsManagerNew.fxml").openStream());
    VersionsManagerNewController controller = (VersionsManagerNewController) fxmlLoader.getController();
    return controller;
}

public VersionsManagerTabelController getTableController() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Pane p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("VersionsManagerTabel.fxml").openStream());
    VersionsManagerTabelController controller = (VersionsManagerTabelController) fxmlLoader.getController();
    return controller;
}

}
```

Comment: How do you bind columns with table? Please, show the fxml

Comment: I added the FXML-Code for you

Comment: Are there two controller classes in your example code? What is `tableCont` and how is it initialized?

Comment: `tableCont` is the referenz to my `VersionsManagerTabelController` Controller class. Sry but i thought the whole Class would be to mutch for you to read and understand so i tried so seperate the most important pieces.

Comment: It's good to be minimal but there's a good chance your errors are in code you haven't posted. (The best way to do this is to write a complete example specifically to post here, rather than posting your entire project.) Can you show how you are getting `tableCont` from the `FXMLLoader`?

Comment: If you are instantiating VersionsManagerTabelController tableCont yourself, you should use fxmlLloader.setController(tableCont);

Comment: Ok, is it not also possible with the approach to get it from the fxmlloader, like i do it in ControllerManager (see last edit)?

I really like JavaFX but in some positions i hate it ... mybe its my only unknown about the technic ...

Comment: You never display the pane you get from the FXMLLoader, so the controllers you are referencing are not the same controllers that are connected to the pane that *is* displayed. Any IDE worth using should be giving you a warning here that `p` is unused. Somewhere in your code you load the FXML file *and display it*. You need the controller that is connected to the pane you display, not some random other controller instance.

Comment: I use the Netbeans IDE in the newest Version but it dont display me some warning. But i think you are right. I make a sample projekt and everything works fine with the same code. The only difference is, that i load the pane with the table as first and only this window. Could you tell me how i can get exactly the right controller?

Comment: I have only one pane with the table which i load every time a button is clicked new with same FXML and same controller the only difference is always the data which is presented.

Comment: But you don't have the same controller. Every time you load the FXML, the `FXMLLoader` creates a new controller instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference you have to the `VersionsManagerTabelController`, `tableCont`, is not referring to the same controller instance that is controlling the UI you actually display. Your `showLxTabel` method should look something like this (I don't know what all the method calls you have here do, as you didn't post a complete example, but this should fix the immediate problem):

```
@FXML
private void showLxTabel(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        cm.setProduct(lx);
        // tableCont.populateDataForTableView(cm.getProduct());
        AnchorPane root=null;
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("VersionsManagerTabel.fxml"));
            root = loader.load();
            VersionsManagerTabelController tableController = loader.getController();
            tableController.populateDataForTableView(cm.getProduct());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        ap_tabelContent.getChildren().clear();
        ap_tabelContent.getChildren().add(root);
        lbl_prduct_overview.setText(lx);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {Logger.getLogger(VersionsManagerMainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Hello James_D, your right it solved my problem ... I dont get the right reference. The problem was that i dont use root=loader.load before i use loader.getController. Thank´s for your help.